# Can we use union in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Does anybody have any idea about unions in hibernate?

I got this question in a interview. My guess is yes, but I'm not sure where and when.

Comment: @gkpstar If a answer fullfil your requirement as answered by Chris Conway, give him upvote as a way recognize his effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no... see here https://www.hibernate.org/117.html#A21

Answer (score 3):

Even though you can't do a true union, you can simulate one if the union is for two different queries for the same entity.  In that case, you can use a `Disjunction` to OR two or more different `DetachedCriteria` queries, using the output of those queries as inputs to a `Restrictions.in` against some column in the main entity.  This method gets you the equivalent of a union.

Comment: an example here would be greatly appreciated.